# How to split a large variable?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, variables, large-data

I'm working with large variables and it can be very slow "looping" through them with `while read line`, I found out that the smaller the variable the faster it works.

How can I split large variable into smaller variables and then read them one by one?

for example,
What I would like to achieve:

```
bigVar=$(echo "$bigVar" | split_var)

for var in "${bigVar[@]}"; do
  while read line; do
    ...
  done <<< "${var}"
done
```

or may be split to bigVar1, bigVar2, bigVar3 etc.. and than read them one by one.

Comment: What kind of data is in `$bigVar`? Can you give a concrete example? You'd probably be better off not storing a huge amount of data in a variable in the first place.

Comment: Don't use whatever `split_var` is or `echo` bigvar, just set `IFS` to whatever you're splitting on

Comment: What about substring expansion? `s="somebigvariable"; echo "${s:0:7} / ${s:7}"` .. or perhaps `for ((i=0; i<${#s}; i+=3)) { echo "${s:i:3}"; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
bigVar=$(someCommand)
while read line
do
   ...
done <<< "$bigVar"
```

Use

```
while read line
do
   ...
done <   <(someCommand)
```

This way, you avoid the problem with big variables entirely, and `someCommand` can output gigabyte after gigabyte with no problem.

If the reason you put it in a variable was to do work in multiple steps on it, rewrite it as a pipeline.

Comment: Just curious, why is the first approach so slow compared to the second approach?

Comment: The first method would read from the process and repeatedly realloc the variable to keep it all in memory, which takes more and more time the bigger the variable gets. It then copies the data for the string expansion, and has to feed it to the while read command. Only then can the while read start reading. With the second approach, the command output is fed directly to the loop, letting it start sooner and do less total work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So the first method has to copy `"$bigVar"` on each iteration of the `while` loop, since it cannot know whether it (`$bigVar`) has changed or not, since the last iteration?

Answer (score 0):

If BigVar is made of words, you could use `xargs` to split it in lines no longer than the maximum length of a command line, usually 32kb or 64kb :

```
someCommand|xargs|while read line
do
    ...
done
```

In this case `xargs` uses its default command, which is `echo`.

I'm curious about what you want to do in the while loop, as it may be optimized with a pipeline.